# Probability and Test Preparation Laziness

Tags: probability

For an upcoming exam my professor has given us a list of 30 questions of which he will select 10 to quiz us on.

My question is: **Assuming I will score a 100% on all of the questions I prepare for, how many of the 30 questions must I prepare for to receive a perfect score on the exam?**

*I understand this may be a slightly humorous question, but I think it holds mathematical merit, and I would like to hear the mathematical foundations of any answer presented*

Additionally, I'm not really interested in moral/pedagogical shortcomings inherent in my question, i'm more so interested in the probability/math involved in solving the question presented.

Comment: If you want an $A$, at least 9 of the 10 that he selects.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. How many must you learn **to achieve what goal**?

Comment: You go to MIT and you aren't willing to learn all 30 questions?!

But seriously, learn them all - it'll help you out in the long run.

Comment: Well, you're planning to pick some, and the instructor is going to pick some.  What probability distribution can be used to model the probability that you will pick some of the same problems as the instructor picks?

Comment: You've left out some essential information: Are the questions equally weighted? Assuming so, What percentage of the answers should be correct to get the grade you want? What is your risk tolerance?

Comment: Hi All, the question has been clarified, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: For the current version of the question (8:41pm), the answer is 30: what if your professor picks exactly the one you skipped?

Comment: To receive a "perfect score" you could study less than all 30, but the probability of achieving a perfect score is less than one.  So to be complete the OP needs to indicate your desired probability of getting a perfect score. Of course the minimum # of questions is 10, but you'd only have a one in about 30 million chance of acing the test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Assuming I will score a 100% on all of the questions I prepare for, how many of the 30 questions must I prepare for to receive a perfect score on the exam?**

You've basically taken probability out the question here.  Like Catalin says, if you skip any one of them, and there's a positive probability the professor chooses that one, then you have a positive probability of a less than perfect score.  So if this is your definition of success, your only option is to study them all.

Here is another question:

> If I decide in advance to select a certain number $n$ of questions to study, what is my expected score?

Now this is sounding more like a probability question.  Your professor is sampling $10$ out of $30$, and you are sampling $n$ of them, without replacement.  Let $X$ be the number of successes among your $n$ trials.  Then $X$ follows a [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution):
$$
    P(X = k) = \frac{\binom{10}{k}\binom{20}{n-k}}{\binom{30}{n}}
$$
You can look up the expected value of this distribution; it is:
$$
    E(X) = n \cdot \frac{10}{30} = \frac{n}{3}
$$
Intuitively, that makes sense; your professor is picking a third of the problems, so you can expect that a third of *your* choices are among the professor's choices.  If you want to ensure an expected score of 9/10, study 27 of the problems.  If 5/10 is your threshold, study half of the problems.

You can further refine the question by trying to find a lower bound for the probability that your score will be above some mark (whether it's passing, or getting an A).  A Google Spreadsheet can do this for you in a few minutes.

---

Now, as a professor, I have some advice:

1. Answering this question yourself might have been a good study exercise.  But asking it online is not the same thing and has much less value for studying.
2. Coming back to the beginning, the most effective, most risk-averse strategy is to study all 30 questions.  Your professor is being extremely generous by limiting to that small a set.

In short, get back to work! `<smile />`

Comment: Hi Professor Leingang, 

thanks for the answer and i'll get back to studying!!!

Answer (score 3):

To be sure to receive a perfect score you must study all 30 questions. Because if there is at least one question you don't study, then it is possible for the instructor to pick exactly that question and given your assumptions you are not guaranteed to get it correct. So, given that you want a guarantee of a perfect score, you have to study all 30.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the passing grade. If the pass is 50% then you need to learn at least 25 of the questions to be safe.

Somebody tell me if I'm wrong, please.